# Replaced tyre and tube, now the rear gears will not stop

Tags: chain, gears

Just put on a tyre and innertube, fits perfectly, but now when I stop pedalling the gears at the back keep moving so the chain just sags down so much that it hits the wheel etc.

Any ideas on how to fix it, or why this is happening?

Cheers guys

Jeremy

Comment: What Mathew said, or perhaps you somehow got the rear derailer and chain improperly positioned while installing the wheel.

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like you have not put the wheel back in properly and have somehow managed to over-tighten the freewheel/freehub, causing it not to spin freely.

You will have to take the wheel out and check that the axle nuts are done up properly and that the freewheel/freehub works. At a guess you are not using a quick-release lever, with nut-style axles you must tighten up each side gradually - 1/2 a turn each side once the wheel is in place or else you can tighten the axle (instead of putting the wheel in).

Do check for 'play' in the wheel once it is back in, if there is any then you will need to get it adjusted - wheel back out time... If you cannot work out what is going on with it, visit a friendly LBS during a quiet weekday to see if they can put it right for you whilst-you-wait.

Comment: i am using a quick release. I will try taking the wheel off and fitting it back on again. I've ordered a new wheel for the bike anyway, because the one i am using at the moment is bent, but it didn't have this problem before i took it off, so you're probably right with the over tightness.

Comment: With the wheel off you can easily check the operation of the freewheel/freehub (that the sprockets are attached to) and verify that it spins easily -- with no resistance -- in one direction and "catches" in the other.  If that's OK, reinstall and only tighten the quick release enough to secure the wheel (not normally a good idea!!!) and see if it's still OK.  Then tighten fully and try again.  If it fails when fully tight the bearings probably need to be adjusted (at your local bike shop).

Comment: Gears refuse to move with everything untightened and wheel off.